# viewresolver unable to redirect to correct view in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Please find the code below:

The viewResolver is unable to direct to the desired View reolved from the controller. I am printing the viewname in the controller. the viewname as printed is correct. but finaly it lands up to a new url!!

Please find below the details!!

**controller**

```
package in.co.linq.StudentAdmissionController;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

public StudentAdmissionController()
{
    super();
    System.out.println("StudentAdmissionController Constructor!!");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/Register" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRegisterForm()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView("Register");
    modelAndView.addObject("msg","Register Me");
    System.out.println("In getRegisterForm");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/HelloPage.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitRegisterForm(@RequestParam("txtname") String name,@RequestParam("txtcollege") String college
        ) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView("HelloPage","msg", "Congrats!! Form submitted for "+name +" in college"+college);
    //modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Congrats!! Form submitted for "+name +" in college"+college);
    //modelAndView.addObject("college", college);
    System.out.println(name+college);
    System.out.println("In submitRegisterForm");
    System.out.println(modelAndView.getViewName());
    System.out.println(modelAndView.getModel());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/HelloPage/{countryName}/{userName}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method(@PathVariable("userName") String userName,@PathVariable("countryName") String countryName) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView("HelloPage","msg", "Congrats!! Form submitted for "+userName+countryName);
    //modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Congrats!! Form submitted for "+name +" in college"+college);
    //modelAndView.addObject("college", college);
    System.out.println(userName+countryName);
    System.out.println("In submitRegisterForm");
    System.out.println(modelAndView.getViewName());
    System.out.println(modelAndView.getModel());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

}

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
     <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**THE ERROR found on URL**
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCUsingRequestParam/HelloPage.html/India/Nilotpal

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCUsingRequestParam/WEB-INF/HelloPage.html/India/Nilotpal.jsp

type Status report

**message /SpringMVCUsingRequestParam/WEB-INF/HelloPage.html/India/Nilotpal.jsp**

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tom
```

**Last few lines on the console**

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/studentadmission/*] onto handler 'studentAdmissionController'
Jun 30, 2015 11:32:54 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SD-StudentAdmission': initialization completed in 19601 ms
```

**Console**

```
NilotpalIndia
In submitRegisterForm
HelloPage
{msg=Congrats!! Form submitted for NilotpalIndia}
```

These lines are the ones printed in the controller. I can see that the view is `HelloPage` but why is it taking in the browser as message message 
`/SpringMVCUsingRequestParam/WEB-INF/HelloPage.html/India/Nilotpal.jsp`

Do

Comment: Post your controller not a snippet.

Comment: Thanks..posted after editing..

Comment: @user1233600 check answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` instead of `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView` ModelView class.

Since new version of Spring 3 or later you can directly return view name as method return value like below

```
@RequestMapping("/HelloPage/{countryName}/{userName}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloSpring(Model model,@PathVariable("userName") String userName,@PathVariable("countryName") String countryName)
{
    model.addAttribute("msg", "Congrats!! Form submitted for "+userName+countryName);
    return "HelloPage";
}
```

You need to take Model object from method parameter, what value or object want to passed to view can be added to Model object and just return view name from method.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! the change in import worked for me :) can u tell me what is the package org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView is for?

Comment: See [this reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227339/what-is-the-difference-in-org-springframework-web-servlet-modelandview-vs-org-sp)

Answer (score 0):

you got a 404 error for that url

: /SpringMVCUsingRequestParam/WEB-INF/HelloPage.html/India/Nilotpal.jsp

your controller is binded to
: /HelloPage/{countryName}/{userName}

if you can post your jsp or the button where you are redirecting to that url , but
propably if you remove the .html from the view that you hit that url it will be ok

Comment: Actually i am directly hitting on the address bar with this URL...no buttons used... what i found was.. the viewname coming to the viewresolver was in the format /HelloPage/{countryName}/{userName} ie: /HelloPage/India/Nilotpal.... so as a result its appending .jsp making it /HelloPage/India/Nilotpal.jsp... whats wrong am not able to detect!!