# what is the difference in org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView vs org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView

Tags: spring-mvc

Can anybody tell the difference between

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
```

and

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView
```

both the ModelAndViews have almost same methods. A significant difference to notice was when I added object to `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView`, the object was not able to reach to the view. In the view the added object was `null`. Do you people know any other significant difference??!! Please add your information here :)

In general the question can also be put as to spot the difference in

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.*;
org.springframework.web.portlet.*;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, they are exactly similar, except that `*.servlet.*` classes are tailored for classical web applications based on servlets, while `*.portlet.*` one are specially tailored for JSR-168 portlets.

This is a deliberate choice from Spring : *As much as possible, the Portlet MVC framework is a mirror image of the Web MVC framework, and also uses the same underlying view abstractions and integration technology*.

But a portlet in much different from a servlet. You could find references on the [JSR-168](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168) and a nice presentation on [What Is a Portlet - O'Reilly Media](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/09/14/what-is-a-portlet.html). Here are some extracts from the latter :

*Portlets are web components--like servlets--specifically designed to be aggregated in the context of a composite page. Usually, many portlets are invoked to in the single request of a portal page. Each portlet produces a fragment of markup that is combined with the markup of other portlets, all within the portal page markup.*

*[Windows for different applications are] developed independently of each other. The developer of the news portlet will create an application and pack it into a .war file. Then the administrator of the portal server will install this .war file on the server and create a page. In the next stage, every user will choose which applications he wants on his page.*

For that reason, Spring portlet classes are very different from portlet ones, even when they present same interface. *The main way in which portlet workflow differs from servlet workflow is that the request to the portlet can have two distinct phases: the action phase and the render phase. The action phase is executed only once and is where any backend changes or actions occur, such as making changes in a database. The render phase then produces what is displayed to the user each time the display is refreshed.*

TL/DR : So `*portlet*` classes have been specialy designed to present a similar interface to the developper (same as `*servlet*`) but are quite different under the hood and must **not** be used in classical (servlet) SpringMVC applications.